# DataFrame transformation in Spark, Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

After I load a json file with:

```
df = sqlContext.read().json(path);
```

I will get my DataFrame in Java Spark. I have for example the next DF:

```
id item1 item2 item3 ....
id1    0     3     4
id2    1     0     2
id3    3     3     0
...
```

I want to transform it in the most easy way to (probably of Object of the class [Rating](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/Rating.html), id and item then to Integer by .hashCode())

```
id   item   ranking
id1  item1    0
id1  item2    3
id1  item3    4
....
id2  item1    1
id2  item2    0
id1  item1    2
...
```

PS Some first attempt to create the flatMap function:

```
void transformTracks() {
        JavaRDD<Rating> = df.flatMap(new Function<Row, Rating>(){
            public Rating call(Row r) {
                for (String i : r) {
                    return Rating(1, 1, r.apply(Double.parseDouble(i)));
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking `flatMap` will do the trick?

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindhoit, sorry, I'm new in Java Spark, can you please show it on example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to forgive me if the syntax is slightly off - I program in Scala nowadays and it's been a while since I used Java - but something along the lines of:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(path);
String[] columnNames = df.columns;

DataFrame newDF = df.flatMap(row -> {
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(columnNames.length);
  String id = (String)row.get(0);

  for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.length, i++) {
    list.add(id, columnNames[i], (int)row.get(i));
  }
  return list;
}).toDF("id", "item", "ranking");
```

Comment: Thank you, I try to understand the flat map function right now, will update my solution above.