# Data transformation in Spark Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe

```
+-----+-----+-----+ .......+-------+
|item1|item2|item3|........| itemN |
+-----+-----+-----+........|-------+
|   v1|   v2|   v3|........| vN----+
|   v4|   v5|   v6|........| v2N---+
+-----+-----+-----+........|-------+
```

here item1 , item2 and item3 are the column names and table consists of 1 row v1,v2,v3.

I want to transform it into

```
colA   colB
item1    v1
item2    v2
item3    v3
 .        .
 .        .
 .        .
```

Here there are two columns lets say colA and colB and rows are as shown.

How to do this transformation in spark using scala?

Comment: could please paste your code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603689/dataframe-transformation-in-spark-java. It is similar to the answer provided as java code. Can you help me with that in scala as I am new to scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `explode`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

input.show()
// +-----+-----+-----+
// |item1|item2|item3|
// +-----+-----+-----+
// |   v1|   v2|   v3|
// |   v4|   v5|   v6|
// +-----+-----+-----+

val columns: Array[String] = input.columns

val result = input.explode(columns.map(s => col(s)): _*) {
  r: Row => columns.zipWithIndex.map { case (name, index) => (name, r.getAs[String](index)) }
}.select($"_1" as "colA", $"_2" as "colB")

result.show()
// +-----+----+
// | colA|colB|
// +-----+----+
// |item1|  v1|
// |item2|  v2|
// |item3|  v3|
// |item1|  v4|
// |item2|  v5|
// |item3|  v6|
// +-----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code . I have one more question , If the number of columns(i.e. item1,item2 ......item n) in initial table are very large then how to do the above thing?

Comment: How large? And why wouldn't the above code work for any (valid) number of columns?

Comment: I don't know the number of columns initially lets say there are 100 columns. I think the above code takes as case the variables i1,i2,i3 corresponding to columns so if there are many columns how will this work?

Comment: Thanks , If values v1,v2 .... are of complex types(say array) rather than string then what change I have to make in above code

Comment: Are they all the same type at least? If they are, just change `r.getAs[String]` to `r.getAs[T]` where T is the type you expect, for example it could be `Array[String]` or `Array[(Int, String)]` or whatever...

Comment: Thanks , I have updated the question and mentioned about the actual schema of v1 . What type  T shall I mention for this schema ?

Comment: Thanks I figured that out.